# How to make a C# REST Call from provider hosted app in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I have created one provider hosted app for remote event receiver. In that, I want to make a REST call with c#. below is my code but I 'm getting 401 unauthorized,

```
            Uri targetWeb = new Uri(clientContext.Web.Url);
            string targetRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(targetWeb);
            var responseToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, targetWeb.Authority, targetRealm);
            HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strApiUrl);
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("{0} {1}", responseToken.TokenType, responseToken.AccessToken));
            endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
            endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            endpointRequest.Credentials = clientContext.Credentials;
            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Can anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you completed all steps that are in this page? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/development-experience-tenant-apponly-permissions-in-sharepoint-online

Comment: Why do you need to make rest call ? Cant you use CSOM code ? Also, what is the REST query that you are making, certain REST call dont work with app only context ?

Answer (score 2):

My problem solved by setting AllowAppOnlyPolicy to true in appmanifest.xml file & passing  realm & AppOnlyAccessToken as Authorization header in Http Request as below,

```
Uri targetWeb = new Uri(clientContext.Web.Url);
string targetRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(targetWeb);
string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, targetWeb.Authority, targetRealm).AccessToken;                
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strApiUrl);
endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "bearer "+ accessToken);
```

Below is reference link from MSDN

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/elevated-privileges-in-sharepoint-add-ins

Answer (score 1):

Please try this [link](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/using-sharepoint-rest-api-in-provider-hosted-apps/) by Waldek Mastykarz.
I guess it is because cross domain call please try [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint/) one also
Hope this will solve your problem.
Please feel free to reply it it works or not

All the best!

Comment: do not post link only answers. the links might go dead in future and this answer will become worthless